# wpf card layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I am very new to wpf. How can I implement CardLayout functionality from java? I have a window  where I need completely switch contents depending on user actions, like different tabs in tabbed pane.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample?

Comment: @Fischermaen, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/layout/ex6/CardLayoutDemo.jnlp

Comment: I am not a java developer - just a simple screenshot showing the desing you want would be sufficient.

Comment: @Fischermaen, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple pages and host them in a frame.
Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) for more information.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CardLayout"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="CardLayout" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,40,0,0" Name="frame1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />

        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem>FirstPage</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>SecondPage</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class CardLayout : Window
{
    private Page[] pages = new Page[] {new Page1(), new Page2()};

    public CardLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame1.Content = pages[((ComboBox) sender).SelectedIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's old but appears first in Google for 'CardLayout WPF': there is also `TabControl` which is really, really useful (at least for me).